# How to load my JavaScript code in WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html, assets

I am trying to use my JavaScript code in Android WebView. First I enable Javascript and load html with my script.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/javascript.html");   
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

After that I load some web page in WebView.

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

When I try to do this

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("myJavascript();", null);
```

I get message :

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: myJavascript is not defined"
```

Function `myJavascript` is defined in "javascript.html" in assets. I suppose that is because after load some page JavaScript is no more in WebView. Can I have loaded in same time HTML with my JavaScriptcode and some web page? I want to define JavaScript in HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

For more information webview settings check out following link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html